# Sound Output not working

Tags: sound, 20.04

I have an AMD Ryzen 7 computer and installed ubuntu 20.04. Recently due to some problems with the brightness, I had to install kernel `5.8.1-050801-generic`. Problem solved.

However, yesterday I turned on my computer and I had "dummy output" in sound configurations, I tried some code lines in the terminal but it still does not recognize the laptop audio (however, it works normally if I plug an HDMI). Codes that I tried:

`sudo apt purge timidity-daemon` -- Package 'timidity-daemon' is not installed, so not removed

`sudo apt-get install --reinstall alsa-base pulseaudio` and
`sudo alsa force-reload`

`mv ~/.config/pulse ~/.config/old_pulse`

`sudo setfacl -m u:$USER:rw /dev/snd/`

(I have rebooted after every attempt)

Comment: Have you tried setting sound output to more than 50%? I had some issues with a sound card, that would only output sound when it was above 50%. I could hear it "turn off" at below 50%. This was on a new Ubuntu 20.04 install.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently

`sudo setfacl -m u:$USER:rw /dev/snd/` 
`rebbot`

works, but I have to do it every time that I start the computer if anyone knows how to make it work permanently would be great.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, and followed a variety of guides, all to no avail.  Then I read in a comment on one of the fora I scoured, and they said they simply removed timidity; now, I see in your post you attempted to remove timidity-daemon, but I think what you really want to do is remove timidity

```
sudo apt-get remove timidity
```

Further investigation reveals that there might be something amiss with how Timidity stores its config file; to whit, the upgraded security measures in 20.04 may have made the config file unavailable for Timidity to read, and thus it's not properly initialized, botching up our sound servers.  If you want to get to the root of this problem, this might be somewhere to start.  That is, of course, assuming that your problem is the same as mine.